# Marvelous Designer to Blender turns half of hoodie black

Tags: uv, shaders

I went through a basic course to build the attached jeans and hoodie skateboarder. Things look great in Marvelous Designer but when exporting to blender as an *MDD* half of the hoodie and the sleeves turn black and one side of the images on the jeans invert to the other.

Marvelous Designer View:

[image: Marvelous Designer View #1]

[image: Marvelous Designer View #2]

Blender View:

[image: Blender View]

Any suggestions on what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: If your question was solved, please be so kind and mark the answer that contributed to the solution as "Accepted Answer". This will make it easier for others to see which way leads to the solution, and the question will no longer appear as unsolved. Thank you! Here you can find more information: [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers). If you still didn't get a solution to your question, please be kind enough to address it.

Answer (score 1):

Since you obviously use *UDIM tiles* in Marvelous Designer (distribution of mapping/texturing over multiple tiles), you would need to switch to *UDIM* in Blender as well.

Here's how to do that:

1. Import the garment/animation into Blender
2. Open the *Image Editor* and switch the image from *Single Image* to *UDIM Tiles*.
3. Add another tile with the *Add Tile* button.
4. Then change the name/path of the image and instead of an explicit number, like *1001*, enter the placeholder `<UDIM>`.

This will allow you to distribute multiple UDIM tiles on your mesh.

[image]

> Don't forget to switch the *Image Texture* to *UDIM Tiles* in the shader as well, if it wasn't done automatically.

[image]